# How to resize container in Microsoft One Note Android app

Tags: notes, microsoft-onenote

I want to resize a text container on Microsoft One Note android app. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

The text container resizing function exist in the app but its hidden. But I found a trick to use it.

1. Click the plus icon and add ink drawing to your note.
2. Draw a short line and click the X icon and close the drawing mode.
3. Click the text you want to resize. The container borders should be visible now.
4. At the top of the container hold left or right arrow icons and swipe to left or to right to resize.

If you want to hide borders, use eraser to delete the drawing. After that container borders should be invisible again